# Remove ItextSharp Image Border of 1 Pixel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, png

The dark gray in this picture is Adobe Reader, the 1 pixel wide white space is what I want to remove, and the dark blue is my image.

[image: The dark gray in this picture is Adobe Reader, the 1 pixel wide white space is what I want to remove, and the dark blue is my image.]

This border appears on both sides of the page.  I've tried making the image obviously larger than the canvas but the 1px border is still there.

Further down the page I have a borderless table, which has colored rows.  The 1px white border does not affect the table, it displays properly.

Here is my code I'm using to add it to the document, logo is a PNG File:

```
        logo.ScalePercent(25f);
        logo.BorderWidth = 0;
        logo.SpacingBefore = 0;
        logo.Border = 0;
        logo.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
        PdfSample.Add(logo);
```

Comment: Can you share a sample file?

Comment: I'm not certain how to upload a PDF or even if that would be allowed

Comment: You cannot upload a PDF to stack overflow itself. It is quite common in such situations, though, to upload the file in question to a file sharing service (as ad-free as possible, e.g. dropbox or google drive public shares) and leave a link to that share here.